# PHP using wrong css file

Tags: php, html, css

I am linking a CSS file like this in my php-program:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href='sa_mal_link_1.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
```

If I change the CSS file, then the updates doesn't work. The php-program finds only the old version of the css-file. There is no other file with the same name on the pc (if i change the name of the css-file then it work, intil I want to update this one too).

Where is the old Version of the css-file coming from? some sort php-cache?
How do I fix it?

Using: wampserver 2.0  +  php Version 5.3.0  +  Apache-server versjon 2.2.11

Comment: PHP has nothing at all to do with this. You're writing it in HTML, not PHP.

Comment: Internet Explorer is the worse to keep things in cache. Even if you do a hard refresh, 99% of the time, that won't work (with IE) and need to actually go in your settings to delete cached files and offline content, IF you are using IE that is. That happened to me as well, the exact same thing when using IE. ***(Shudders & Groans)***

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like your browser is caching the old page. Clear the browser’s cache, close and reopen the browser.  Try again.

Answer (score 2):

ctrl+F5 refrsh browser or clear cache

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't pass the `css` file though `php`, they are served directly by the Apache Server.

Depending on the configuration of the Apache Server (e.g. if `mod_expires` is active), static elements like css, images, js files could have an an expire header that is set e.g. for a week or even a month. If this header is set the browser wouldn't request the resource anymore for that time interval if it has it in cache.

For development either disable caching in your browser or disable the e.g. `mod_expires` on your development pc.

Answer (score 1):

Above answers are correct, but if those answers aren't enough (which can also be solved by hitting CTRL + R), try disabling the cache in your .htaccess file. If you don't have one, open notepad, and type *Header add "disablevcache" "true"*, and save it as .htaccess into your root folder. Refresh a few times with CTRL + R, should work.

**EDIT**

What I mean by "aren't enough", is that the cache might not be the browser, but in fact your server. You should try all of the all answers suggested to see which one works best :)

Comment: Isn't `disablevcache` only important for varnish cache servers? While that one is not mention in the question, there is more then one caching server, and `disablevcache` is only for one caching server.

Comment: You're 100% right, but I find that caching can often be unpredictable, which I why I suggested it as last resort alternative.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know how to clear your cashe, try another browser that you never use.

On chrome, open the inspector by right clicking the web page, then click inspect element. While the inspector is open, hold the left click button on the refresh button at the top of the screen. It will drop down a menu, this is a recent addition.

You now (while the inspector is open) have the option to reload, hard reload, and hard reload + clear cashe.

This is really useful while you are working on the web.

There is also an option in the inspector of chrome that will always clear your cashe and reload anytime you reload while the inspector is open. That is how mine is set up.

If you want to do that, then click the gear at the bottom right of the screen, then in the general tab, it's the "clear cashe on refresh" box.